# Capital letter in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

executing this piece of code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            Date date = null;
                            try {
                                date = sdfIn.parse(value11);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            SimpleDateFormat sdfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");

                            System.out.println(sdfOut.format( date ));
```

I an getting this output `nov 23, 2005` instead of `Nov 23, 2005` which would be much better.
Does anybody knows how to change it??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exact strings that get generated depend on the locale you're in.  If you just use

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
```

then the system default locale will be used. Your default locale probably renders the month as `nov` rather than `Nov`.

if you want a specific locale to be used, pass it in to the constructor, e.g.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: pretty much exactly what I was too slow to say :)